# Java API to emulate browser

Tags: java, junit

I'm looking for a Java API which allows me navigating through HTTP Pages and read the content, just like a Browser. The difficult part of it is that navigation includes performing some **actions** (e.g. list box selection and submit) and **JavaScript** interaction (e.g. Yes or No dialog). Is there such API which can be used for this purpose ? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/ . It sucks, but there's nothing better

Comment: [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: See also [Arquillian Graphene](http://arquillian.org/modules/graphene-extension/) and [js-test-driver](https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll use then HTML Unit as I have knowledge of JUnit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to diverge a bit from Java and enter the realm of [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), you could give a try to [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) and [Spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/).

Groovy code compiles into Java code and runs into a JRE. Geb is effectively a domain specific language that allows you to model HTML pages with a syntax that is more friendly and intuitive than Selenium.  Geb and Spock work well [together](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/testing.html) with can make your life a bit easier. For sure, the is a learning curve, but in the end your tests are much easier to write, read and maintain.

For some learning material you could also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249371/learning-geb-and-spock).

Comment: Thanks for the useful link and suggestion. As I need a quick implementation, I'll follow the advice from @BackSlash who suggested HTMLUnit

Comment: @user2824073 Be careful what you define as "quick". The initial cost of moving into Geb/ Spock can be absorbed after a couple of weeks. In other works, if you plan to invest more that two weeks for browser testing, then it is probably worth it to make the move.